# OSMdroid Cannot get current location in android studio

Tags: android, osmdroid

Firstly I am new to OSMdroid.
I know there is other similar questions on this topic but there are no recent questions and the answers to the older questions don't work on my code...

I can't get the current location using OSMDroid.
I have used the simple tutorial given on github and the suggestions given in previous questions. 
I have the latest version of OSMDroid but when I try to add a tag for the current location, nothing comes up.

I don't even get errors, the map just displays with no marker for the current location. Help! Here is my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it is very annoying!

```
Java Class
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        //important! set your user agent to prevent getting banned from the osm servers
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

        mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        IMapController mapController = mMapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(9);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(52.1237453, 6.9293683);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

        this.mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(ctx),mMapView);
        this.mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mLocationOverlay);
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tilesource="Mapnik" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible reasons.

1) Your manifest is missing permissions for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

2) If the target SDK is 23 or newer, you have to ask for user level GPS permissions before creating the `GpsMyLocationProvider`

There are examples of both in the osmdroid sample application's source code, located here: 
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/intro/PermissionsFragment.java#L94

and here:

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L24

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help finially got it working there. I put in the permissions and rebuilt the code and it now works. Thanks again!